# Wrong event.target when clicking button child element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following element representing a button in a survey:

```
<button name={id} value={value} onclick={handleChoiceClick} className="choice__button">
   <img src={image} className="choice__button-image"/>
   <span className="choice__button-title">Button title</span>
</button>
```

The `handleChoiceClick` function triggers the `handleChange` function and stores some data by the button's name and value:

```
const handleChoiceClick = (e) => {
   handleChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
};
```

This works fine, but when I click one of the child elements inside the button (image or span) the `handleChoiceClick` function gets another event.target as a parameter and the name and values are undefined.

What is the best way to solve this issue? Checking the `event.target` inside the `handleChoiceClick` or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I'm not finding a straightforward dupetarget for this. There must be one, but... :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you want the element that you hooked the event on, use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) rather than [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). In your case, that will always be the `button` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChoiceClick = (e) => {   
   var buttonElement = e.target.closest('.choice__button')
   handleChange(buttonElement.name, buttonElement.value);
};
```

This can give you the name and value of the required button although the target is any other element inside the button.